# Connecting to MySQL causes error "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database using my ASP.NET Web Forms Application. I'm carrying out a test to Bind the data from the MySQL database to a `GridView`.

Here is my code:

```
Dim strMySQLConn As String = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Database=database_name;Server=ip_address;UID=username;PWD=password;"
    Dim MySQLConn As New OdbcConnection(strMySQLConn)

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

            Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
            Dim cmdMySQL As New OdbcDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM categorymaster", MySQLConn)

            MySQLConn.Open()

            cmdMySQL.Fill(ds, "prjs")

            gv.DataSource = ds.Tables("prjs").DefaultView
            gv.DataBind()


            MySQLConn.Close()

        End If
    End Sub
```

However, when the MySQL database connection is made (`MySQLConn.Open()`), the following error is returned:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not
>   found and no default driver specified

Why is this and how can I prevent it from happening?

Also, what are the possible reasons for seeing this error? If login credentials were incorrect, would this error be shown?

Comment: simillar question check this out it my help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294024/data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified

Comment: @karthi - I've changed my conn string to `DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};`, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Is the driver installed? ODBC gives this error if it can't load the driver as well.

Comment: @Romain "MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver" is installed, but I'm still getting this error

Comment: @Curt ASP.net has to be able to load it. If your machine is x86_64, you might have installed either the 32- or 64-bits version. You'll need to have installed the one with the same architecture as your ASP server.

Comment: My OS is 64 bit, and I've installed the 64 bit driver. Furthermore, if I check my list of drivers, "MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver" is now displaying on the driver list. What else could be wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue was caused because I was installing a `64-bit` MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver, because my OS is running 64 bit.

Because I've been trying to solve this for days, as a long shot I deleted the driver, and installed `32-bit` MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver.

This has fixed the error and I'm now making a successful connection.

Comment: How did you see the 32bit Driver in the ODBC Manager Console? I've problems with 64 bit driver and based on your reply, installed 32bit on Win 7 64 bit. But I'm not able to see the driver in the ODBC Manager.

Answer (score 4):

Curt was right.  I was having this exact issue. Since I had MySQL Workbench installed on my workstation, I assumed I had the drivers installed; Nope. 
Installing the driver plus calling it by the correct version, and adding command "Provider=MSDASQL;" to the connection string due to the fact that I'm on a 64-bit system solved the issue for me.
If you want to see all the ODBC drivers installed on your Windows system, open the registry editor to:

> \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers.

There you will find out if the MySQL driver is installed, and if so, its correct name.

[This Link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/3.51.html) will take you to the MySQL Drivers Download site.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Russell S This is not really an answer to the OP's question (Original Poster). You should write this as a comment.

Comment: Must have 50 reputation to comment. Now I'm negative. Oh poo :0)

Comment: I've rephrased the answer. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check to see if the driver is installed. [Here is a guide to getting the list](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/07/07/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-odbc-drivers-that-are-installed-on-a-computer.aspx)

Check to see if you have any installed and also make sure your version matches with the one in your connection string.

You should be able to download a driver [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc)

Comment: Cheers, I've installed ""MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver" now, but I'm still getting this error

Comment: @Curt, are you sure that you can access the DB? Have you tried to access using another tool? such as [this](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) or using a [UDL File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e38h511e(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Login credentials are correct. This has been tested by connecting using MySQL Administrator

Answer (score 3):

My solution of "Data source name not found" (with 5.2.4 ODBC ansi driver, Win7 64bit):

1) Install 64bit ODBC MySQL driver - it should be visible in ODBC Drivers.

2) Install 32bit ODBC MySQL driver - it is invisible in ODBC drivers, but create a "shadow" installation in Program Files x86.

That's all.

Comment: This did it for me. I installed the 32-bit one first and it didn't work (because I knew 64-bit wouldn't work). But after installing both, it solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I had on my code

DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver}, but when I did look up the ODBC trough the windows searcher engine I found an app called *ODBC Data Sources*, in that app under the *Drivers* tab I found the name of the drives was {MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm connecting java 7 with ODBC and this worked for me

```
String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
String connectionString = "jdbc:odbc:\"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 Unicode Driver};DSN=refde;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
```